# How to set the default value for a column in a MySQL table using Liquibase changelog.yaml file and Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I am creating a `MySQL` table in my `Spring Boot` application using `Liquibase`. But when I run `mvn clean install` I see an error where it is not able to create the table because the default value specified in the `db.changelog-master.yaml` file is not correct.

Not sure what's wrong. Please guide.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/agrisell-db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456
```

**src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml**

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 1
      author: nital.chandel
      changes:
        - createTable:
            tableName: state
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: state_cd
                  type: varchar(2)
                  autoIncrement: false
                  constraints:
                    primaryKey: true
                    nullable: false
              - column:
                  name: state_name
                  type: varchar(100)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                    unique: true
              - column:
                  name: create_modified_by
                  type: varchar(50)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  defaultValue: 'admin'
              - column:
                  name: create_modified_dt
                  type: timestamp
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  defaultValue: current_timestamp
              - column:
                  name: active
                  type: char(1)
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  defaultValue: 'Y'
```

**Error Log after running "mvn clean install"**

```
2019-01-19 23:28:25.249  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : CREATE TABLE `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID INT NOT NULL, `LOCKED` BIT(1) NOT NULL, LOCKGRANTED datetime NULL, LOCKEDBY VARCHAR(255) NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK PRIMARY KEY (ID))
2019-01-19 23:28:25.389  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2019-01-19 23:28:25.405  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : DELETE FROM `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2019-01-19 23:28:25.405  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : INSERT INTO `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, `LOCKED`) VALUES (1, 0)
2019-01-19 23:28:25.405  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT `LOCKED` FROM `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
2019-01-19 23:28:25.421  INFO 10360 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully acquired change log lock
2019-01-19 23:28:25.926  INFO 10360 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Creating database history table with name: `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOG
2019-01-19 23:28:25.926  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : CREATE TABLE `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, AUTHOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, FILENAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, DATEEXECUTED datetime NOT NULL, ORDEREXECUTED INT NOT NULL, EXECTYPE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, MD5SUM VARCHAR(35) NULL, `DESCRIPTION` VARCHAR(255) NULL, COMMENTS VARCHAR(255) NULL, TAG VARCHAR(255) NULL, LIQUIBASE VARCHAR(20) NULL, CONTEXTS VARCHAR(255) NULL, LABELS VARCHAR(255) NULL, DEPLOYMENT_ID VARCHAR(10) NULL)
2019-01-19 23:28:25.988  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOG
2019-01-19 23:28:25.988  INFO 10360 --- [           main] l.c.StandardChangeLogHistoryService      : Reading from `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOG
2019-01-19 23:28:26.004  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT * FROM `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
2019-01-19 23:28:26.004  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `agrisell-db`.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
2019-01-19 23:28:26.004  INFO 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : CREATE TABLE `agrisell-db`.state (state_cd VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, state_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, create_modified_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'admin' NOT NULL, create_modified_dt timestamp DEFAULT 'current_timestamp' NOT NULL, active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_STATE PRIMARY KEY (state_cd), UNIQUE (state_name))
2019-01-19 23:28:26.004 ERROR 10360 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet            : Change Set classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::1::nital.chandel failed.  Error: Invalid default value for 'create_modified_dt' [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE `agrisell-db`.state (state_cd VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, state_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, create_modified_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'admin' NOT NULL, create_modified_dt timestamp DEFAULT 'current_timestamp' NOT NULL, active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_STATE PRIMARY KEY (state_cd), UNIQUE (state_name))]
2019-01-19 23:28:26.020  INFO 10360 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Successfully released change log lock
2019-01-19 23:28:26.020  WARN 10360 --- [           main] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::1::nital.chandel:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid default value for 'create_modified_dt' [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE `agrisell-db`.state (state_cd VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, state_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, create_modified_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'admin' NOT NULL, create_modified_dt timestamp DEFAULT 'current_timestamp' NOT NULL, active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_STATE PRIMARY KEY (state_cd), UNIQUE (state_name))]
2019-01-19 23:28:26.020  INFO 10360 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-01-19 23:28:26.020  INFO 10360 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2019-01-19 23:28:26.035  INFO 10360 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-01-19 23:28:26.035 ERROR 10360 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::1::nital.chandel:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid default value for 'create_modified_dt' [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE `agrisell-db`.state (state_cd VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, state_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, create_modified_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'admin' NOT NULL, create_modified_dt timestamp DEFAULT 'current_timestamp' NOT NULL, active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_STATE PRIMARY KEY (state_cd), UNIQUE (state_name))]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) [spring-boot-test-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159) [surefire-junit4-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418) [surefire-booter-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml::1::nital.chandel:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid default value for 'create_modified_dt' [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE `agrisell-db`.state (state_cd VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, state_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, create_modified_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'admin' NOT NULL, create_modified_dt timestamp DEFAULT 'current_timestamp' NOT NULL, active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_STATE PRIMARY KEY (state_cd), UNIQUE (state_name))]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:637) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:53) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:78) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:202) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:305) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Invalid default value for 'create_modified_dt' [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE `agrisell-db`.state (state_cd VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL, state_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, create_modified_by VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT 'admin' NOT NULL, create_modified_dt timestamp DEFAULT 'current_timestamp' NOT NULL, active CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y' NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_STATE PRIMARY KEY (state_cd), UNIQUE (state_name))]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:356) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:57) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:125) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1229) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1211) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:600) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Invalid default value for 'create_modified_dt'
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:782) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:666) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
        at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:352) ~[liquibase-core-3.6.2.jar:na]
        ... 57 common frames omitted

2019-01-19 23:28:26.035 ERROR 10360 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@42a48628] to prepare test instance [com.allianceagriskmanagement.agrisell.AgrisellRestApplicationTests@2a2b7a35]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the above problem by replacing `defaultValue: current_timestamp` with

```
defaultValue: now()
```

in the `db.changelog-master.yaml` file

`now()` is a function that returns a constant time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is a **synonym** for `now()`